# How do I fix: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldjiosdk-core

Tags: cmake, linker-errors, raspbian, dji-sdk

I downloaded and installed the DJI-OSDK on my Raspberry Pi and was able to run the Samples on the DJI Assistant simulation. However, when I try to make and build my own project (with CMake), I run into the problem:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldjiosdk-core
```

The CMake file contains this line:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} djiosdk-core)
```

My questions are:

1. How do I link the djiosdk-core library?
2. How do I create my own project within OSDK so that it builds correctly?

I am using a N3 with the RPi.

I've also ran: `$ dpkg -L djiosdk-core` with output:

```
dpkg-query: package 'djiosdk-core' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. You have no libdjiosdk-core at all
2. It is out of system runpath
3. It has different name

Try to search it:

`$ find . -type f -name "*djiosdk-core*"`

Find package name:

`$ apt-cache search djiosdk`

then list all package’s files:

`$ dpkg-query -L [package_name]`

If you have no this developer library, then install this SDK from source (see its wiki)

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldjiosdk-core
```

is a linker error, which indicates that the linker does know where to find the `djiosdk-core` library. If this library is *not* in your typical system paths, the linker will not know how to find it. So you must provide the **full** path to the library in your [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#overview) CMake command:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /your/path/to/libs/libdjiosdk-core.so)
```